# Viewing non-project file(s) in Maven-based IntelliJ projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We use Maven and IntelliJ for a number of multi-module projects.  We're set up so that the root `pom.xml` file IS the project file.  Developers, after importing a root `pom.xml`, may customize their project's environment, but we do not put IntelliJ projects under source control or otherwise save them.  When a developer starts working on a new project for the first time, she imports the root `pom.xml` and is off and running.

There's a problem with this practice.  We have other files in our source trees that aren't directly related to Maven and building our Java artifacts, but that we'd like to view and modify in IntelliJ.  These unrelated files don't show up in the IntelliJ project explorer.  In the cases where we have whole unrelated directories, we do this by adding extra "Content Root" definitions to the project on a ad-hoc basis.  But if an individual file exists in the root of the source tree, or some other project directory, and is not used by the Maven build process, it doesn't show up in IntelliJ, and you can't add the root of the source tree as a new "Content Root".  For example, we have a `Jenkinsfile` at the root of our tree that Maven doesn't care about, but we as developers certainly do.  We currently have to edit this file in another code editor.

Is there a good way to cause these sorts of files to show up in the IntelliJ project view(s)?  Ideally, we'd like there to be some way to add something to a `pom.xml` file to cause these to show up and otherwise be ignored by our builds.  If we have to though, a way to add these files ad-hoc would be ok.  We can't find any consistent way to do this. Can anyone tell us how to solve this problem?

UPDATE: I am not storing the IntelliJ project files at the root of my source tree.  The root pom.xml file is an aggregate pom that does not produce anything.  Here is what my "Project" view looks like:

[image: My IntelliJ Project View]

The root of the source tree is inletfetch_if2, which you can see has no representation here.  The if2_all node is where my IntelliJ project files live.

Comment: Per @CrazyCoder's suggestion, I tried to reproduce my problem via a minimal set of project modules laid out the way our main source tree is.  I couldn't reproduce the problem...the root files were right there.  So then I renamed my problematic project and created it again from the root pom.  And to my surprise...the files were there in my new project as well.  I tried importing in different ways (select pom.xml as project, select root directory, "New->From existing sources...").  I got different results, but I could always get to the files at the root of my source tree...

Comment: ...  So it seems that my existing project is just messed up somehow.  It's missing the node representing the root of the tree (the root directory) and so won't let me get to the files in that directory.  I have no guess as to how or why it got that way.  But I'm good.  I'll just work from the new IntelliJ project I just built. Thanks Crazy! for having me try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA Project view will display the files located in the project root next to the parent `pom.xml`:

[image: multimodule]

You can [get this sample project here](https://github.com/sameergarg/examples/tree/master/hello-world-ear).

As you can see, the parent Maven aggregate project is located in the root of the `hello-world-ear` directory, there are 2 sub-projects located in the `packaging` and `hello-world-war` directories.

If you add `Jenkinsfile` in the project root, it will be displayed in the Project View.

Do you use some other configuration that has a different structure? If so, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Comment: Looking at my setup, I don't store the IntelliJ project files at the root of our tree, where the root pom.xml file is.  I guess because of that, and because the root pom is an aggregate pom, I don't have a node in my project view representing the root of our source tree.

Comment: I will try to put together a minimal example